# python: changing the value of a specific column in 2-d list

Tags: python

I have a 2-d list (list of 2-tuples):

```
results = [("a", 0.1234), ("b", 0.32345), ("c", 0.54321)]
```

and I would like to change it to be:

```
>> [('a', '12.34'), ('b', '32.34'), ('c', '54.32')]
```

My thought was to do something like this:

```
results = [(x[0], "%.2f" % (x[1] * 100)) for x in results]
```

And it works, is there a better way of doing it (according to `import this` guidelines), as it seems that accessing the value `x[0]` is <s>not efficient</s> ugly. btw - I can change it to be a list of lists instead of tuples, if that changes anything e.g:

```
results = [["a", 0.1234], ["b", 0.32345], ["c", 0.54321]]
```

and respectively:

```
>> [['a', '12.34'], ['b', '32.34'], ['c', '54.32']]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not efficient"?

Comment: The best answer should be changing it in-place. Also, not efficient is maybe the wrong term here - it should be changed to 'ugly'

Comment: I don't see why it's ugly. Of course, unpacking makes it slightly more readable, but a list comprehension is definitely your best option

Comment: Changing a tuple is not possible. Changing a list is possible, but it's much "uglier" than the functional approach of using a list comprehension. I don't see what you want to know here, seeing that you already have a working solution. What's the problem?

Comment: @NiklasB. Actually Robinson's unpacking suggestion makes it less ugly and that is what I needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [tuple unpacking](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples#Packing_and_Unpacking):

```
[(a, "%.2f" % (b * 100.0)) for a, b in results]
```

Comment: but let's say that in the future I would like to add more columns to result e.g. `results = [["a",0.2,True], ...]`

Comment: @zenpoy: Then you just do that. You can read about list comprehensions and unpacking in the docs :)

Comment: This won't do what you expect.

Comment: `a, b in results` will give `ValueError: too many values to unpack`, no?

Comment: @zenpoy: If each list item is larger than two or three items, this would be an unwieldy solution- use something similar to your original approach. Though if you have a lot of items in each list (many columns) this will become inefficient since you're reconstructing the list many times. (If each is a list, and you can modify it in place, it would be better just to use a for loop). (Also, what Niklas B. means is to extend the number of items like `a, b, c`)

Comment: Of course it wouldn't be `a, b` any longer then. I think the downvote is quite rude, because the answer is correct and useful.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: why does this not do what I expect? And how does your answer differ from mine other than giving the OP more digits than he wants?

Comment: I'm guessing @BurhanKhalid was referring to the point that if you have integers rather than floats as a value in the second column, it raises an exception. While the asker didn't mention this as a possibility, it's worth bringing up, and I've added it to my answer.

Comment: @DavidRobinson - that's a good point: although it's always a float,  `explicit is better than implicit`.

Comment: @zenpoy: I see that somebody had their share of dogmatic and over-generalized programming wisdom :)

Comment: Also, your answer assumes the values will be int or float, if its a string (as in the result); then it also won't work.

Comment: @Burhan: Why the heck would it be a string? Just state in the documentation that it's ought to be a float. We're not talking about PHP here